# Matlab: assign to matrix with column\row index pairs

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the values of multiple points in a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850368/how-can-i-change-the-values-of-multiple-points-in-a-matrix)

I have a matrix `A` and three vectors of the same length, `r`, holding the indexes of the rows to assign to, `c`, holding the indexes of the columns to assign to, and `v` containing the actual values to assign.

What I want to get is `A(r(i),c(i))==v(i)` for all `i`. But doing

```
A(r,c)=v;
```

Doesn't yield the correct result as matlab interprets it as choosing every possible combination of `r` and `c` and assigning values to it, for instance

```
n=5;
A=zeros(n);
r=1:n;
c=1:n;

A(r,c)=1;
```

Yields a matrix of ones, where I would like to get the identity matrix since I want `A(r(i),c(i))==1` for each `i`, that is only elements on the diagonal should be affected.

How can I achieve the desired result, without a `for` loop?

Comment: similar question: [Converting a matlab matrix to a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931545/converting-a-matlab-matrix-to-a-vector)

Comment: @Amro - While I agree the answers to both questions are very similar, the questions are different - I wanted to know how to assign to a matrix, while the other question wants to know how to covert a matrix into a vector. One wouldn't reach the other question when looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: I did not down-vote you, I simply linked to the other question as being similar (as opposed to voting to close as duplicate)..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the values of multiple points in a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6850368/52738)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer - one needs to use linear indexing, that is convert the column\row pairs into a single index:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), r,c);
A(idx)=v;
```