# Indexing a set of indices to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, mask, indices, matrix-indexing

I retrieved all non-white pixel from an image :

```
[ii, jj] = find(BlackOnWhite < 255)
```

Then I tried to index those pixel coordinates to a matrix :

```
image(ii, jj) = 0
```

But zeros do not appear in the expected places. How can I put zeros only in the places specified by pairs from `ii` and `jj` (i.e. `[ii(1), jj(1)], [ii(2), jj(2)]` etc.)?

Comment: But I don't have the expected result. Which are the expected results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: assign to matrix with column\row index pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119581/matlab-assign-to-matrix-with-column-row-index-pairs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do that is to use [**linear indexing**](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/). This means using a single index that traverses all entries in the matrix (down, then across). In your case:

- Use `find` with one ouput. This gives the linear indices of the desired pixels.
- Use that to index into the matrix.

So:

```
ind = find(BlackOnWhite < 255);
image(ind) = 0;
```

You can even remove `find` and use [**logical indexing**](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/). This means that the result of the logical comparison is directly used as an index:

```
ind = BlackOnWhite < 255;
image(ind) = 0;
```

The problem with the code shown in your question is that `ii` and `jj` are being used as ["**subscript indices**"](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). This selects *all pairs* formed by any value from `ii` and any value from `jj`, which is not what you want.

If you have subscripts `ii` and `jj` like in your question and you need to only select *corresponding values* from each subscript (instead of all pairs), you can use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to **convert to a linear index**:

```
[ii, jj] = find(BlackOnWhite < 255);
image(sub2ind(size(image), ii, jj)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because MATLAB treats the subscripts as a grid, which means roughly "set all intersection of any of `ii` and any of `jj` to zero" **and not** "set the locations specified by these separate pairs of coordinates to zero".

In some cases (but not this one) you might need to convert a set of subscripts to indices, in which case I suggest familiarizing yourself with [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).

As mentioned in the other answer(s), the best thing to do in your case is simply:

```
image(BlackOnWhite < 255) = 0;
```