# How to index a sparse set of elements in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a big matrix and I want to retrieve a set of values in different locations, using one call statement.

So for example, I want to retrieve (2,3), (6,7), and (15,19)

I know I can do the following;

```
myRows = [2 6 15];
myCols = [3 7 19];
myTempResults = myBigMatrix(myRows, myCols);    % Which will return all possible pairs
% Then I can do
%
myFinalResults = diag(myTempResults);
```

But I'd like to know the **correct/right** way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a matlab matrix to a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931545/converting-a-matlab-matrix-to-a-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `sub2ind` or calculate the linear indices yourself:

```
a = rand(20,30); % 20 x 30 matrix
myRows = [2 6 15];
myCols = [3 7 19];

% method 1, sub2ind
a(sub2ind(size(a),myRows,myCols))

% or calculate it yourself, Matlab is column major
% and 1-based so row/col (i,j) is (j-1)*nrow+i
a( (myCols-1)*size(a,1) + myRows )
```